# Struts2 and jsp form submit using jquery ajax post and getting a toast like message which comes and disappears?

Tags: jsp, jquery, struts2, toast

I am using struts2 for my web application development. In a registration form there I want to use `query ajax`, so that the form gets submitted **asynchronously** and on a successful form submission **I can get a server side success message in form of a toast** or a  element that comes and disappears.

Well for that I have tried a lot and somewhere achieved this thing but not using `jquery ajax` but normal `javascript and ajax` rather.

The flow of the code is as follows:

- `Home.jsp` page with the form contained.

  ```
          <s:form theme="simple" action="registrationForDemo"> <table>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="username" /></td>
                      <td><s:textfield name="uName"
                              cssClass="textfield" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="password" /></td>
                      <td><s:password name="password"
                              cssClass="textfield" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="email" /></td>
                      <td><s:textfield name="email"
                              cssClass="textfield" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="contact no." /></td>
                      <td><s:textfield name="contactNo"
                              cssClass="textfield" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="location" /></td>
                      <td><s:textfield name="location"
                              cssClass="textfield" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><s:label value="category" /></td>
                      <td><s:select list="{'Hospital','Doctor','Clinic','Others'}" name="category"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td><s:submit
                              value="Submit" cssClass="button" /></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </s:form>
  ```
- The file where the mapping are defined i.e. struts.xml.

[image: struts.xml file]

- When data is saved successfully in the database the output page is again the same page.

Now Using ajax and jquery I want to know how to achieve the required functionality. Where to pass the action from ... and how to go further... ??

Comment: would you post your answer? I have the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726913/how-to-show-server-responses-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for me the solution was `jquery.html()` function. Where I passed the other html content to get the work done. [Jquery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Jquery is awesome and light weight too.

Answer (score 5):

Well if you have achieved it with simple java-script and AJAX and i believe that it's not different with what you will do with using Jquery.
Jquery is nothing different that java-script as its a library build don java script to make developer life happy.

You can submit your form using Jquery post method and can send a string from the server on successful registration something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

For more fine control i will suggest you to use [Struts2-Json](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) plugin and Jquery Json feature to send data to the server and get back results from the server something like

```
var formInput='val='+val;
   $.getJSON('myaction',formInput,function(data) {
     $.each(data.myData,function(index, value){
       alert(index);
});
});
```

For more details refer to this tutorial

- [ajax-dynamic-content-with-struts2-jquery-and-json-plugin](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/07/12/ajax-dynamic-content-with-struts2-jquery-and-json-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

```
//saving category button
    $("#save").on({click:function () {
        if (!($("#subcategory").val().length == 0)) {
            $.ajax({url:"savecategory", data:$("#savecategoryform").serialize(), type:"post", dataType:"json", success:function (data) {
                alert("Successfully Saved");
            }});
        }
    }});


<form id="savecategoryform">
                        <table id="addtable">
                            <thead id="subcategoryhead">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <input type="text" name="strMainCategoryName"
                                            value="Main Category" width="80" id="maincategory"
                                            class="inputmaintext">
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="left">
                                        <img src="../images/plus.png" width="18" height="18"
                                            id="addmaincategory" hovertext="Add" class="link">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="subcategorybody"></tbody>
                        </table>
                        <input type="button" value="Save" id="save">
                    </form>
```