# How to show server responses using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I need to submit a form and show related message (submitted / something went wrong) using ajax. I have a page with a form to submit to server, I am using javascript/ajax to send requests to server. how to receive the responses from server and show them on the page ?

Currently I have written "xmlhttp.responseText" , but how about if I need to show the responses of server ?

I used the following as well to show the message but it only works when I send the request using my form not the javascript.

Any other way to show value of variables? after server responded to ajax request?

property

```
      <s:property value="message"/>
```

javascript function

```
function AddToWatchList(value){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } 
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get","add?myvalue="+value,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Server Code**

```
 ...
 private String message;
  public String add(){
    ....
    this.message = "added";
    return "success";
}
 getter and setter of message
 .....
```

xmlhttp.responseText is not the correct answer as I want to show the value of a specific variable, lets say message variable on the server.

**Mir Moordio, provided a great solution but is there any better method to do this ?**

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

Comment: whats the negative vote for?

Comment: So you're saying that the data isn't in the `xmlhttp.responseText`?

Comment: @squint no it is not. It is in a specific variable called message. when server receive the information try to add them to DB then set the value of message variable accordingly.

Comment: @JackRamzi: So if I understand you correctly, the server isn't sending the response that you want, and you're asking how to make the server send the correct data?

Comment: @AdnanAkbar read the question again please

Comment: @squint yes or how to show the value of "message" variable that is set by server.

Comment: do you have a server code with you?

Comment: @AdnanAkbar question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the server response to a separate page and display that page using jquery.html or xmlhttp.responseText.

```
private String message;
  public String add(){
    ....
    this.message = "added";
    return "message";   
}
```

struts.xml

```
<result name="message">message.jsp</result>
```

message.jsp

```
   required library goes here
   <s:property value="message"/>
```

The rest of your code should be fine.

Comment: great it works thanks, but is there any better method ?

Comment: sorry I do not know any other method